# JFreechart Gantt chart combined Time series Chart

Tags: charts, jfreechart

I'm working on developing a tool that will have two JFreechart Chart panels -

1. A Gantt chart at the top
2. A Time series chart at the bottom

Now, my requirement is :

- Both these charts should align and have same x-axis
- When I zoom in on the Gantt chart, it has to zoom in the time series chart too.

I've done some study on this already, but could not find a way out - Here is what I tried:

- XYTaskDataset cannot be used on Gantt chart
- Could not create overlay charts either as the Gantt chart's data set is "GanttCategoryDataset" and the timeseries is "XYDataset".

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Will either of the solutions here [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216242/jfreechart-link-axes)

Comment: Thanks, Graham - Will try that solution..

Comment: Cross-poted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116752).